# How to use the re.search syntax to match a list of keywords from a pdf document?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am looking to use the re.search function that will use of list of my keywords to extract page numbers, where the text contain these keywords

```
# Get number of pages
NumPages = file.getNumPages()

# Enter string to be searched here
String = 'Acquisition'

mylist =[]
for i in range(0, NumPages):
    PageObj = file.getPage(i)
    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    if re.search(String,Text):
        mylist.append(str(i))
print(mylist)
```

The code list the page numbers where the text contain the keyword "acquisition" at the moment. However, I want the string variable to contain multiple keywords that will either or retrieve the page numbers if matched of that makes sense?

Comment: No worries, i got it to work.

Comment: my_keywords = ['identifiable','intangible']

mylist =[]
for i in range(0, NumPages):
    PageObj = file.getPage(i)
    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    if re.search(r"(("+'.*'.join(my_keywords)+r"))",Text):
        mylist.append(str(i))
print(mylist)

Comment: Do you want pages with all your keywords or pages with one of your keywords?

Comment: try ```r'|'.join(my_keywords)``` as regex

Comment: pages containing both keywords. Sorry, I am new to programming! Is there a way in python to display the pages that is being returned by the function described above? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Totally doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using sets looks handy because it automatically deduplicates results found by `re.findall` and you can easily compare them to your keywords without to take the order in which they are found in account:

```
keywords = {'identifiable', 'intangible'}
pat = re.compile(r'\b(' + (r'|'.join(keywords)) + r')\b')

mypages = []

for i in range(0, NumPages):
    Text = file.getPage(i).extractText().lower()
    if set(pat.findall(Text)) == keywords:
        mypages.append(i)

print(mypages)
```

The second line build a regex pattern: an alternation with your keywords: `\b(identifiable|intangible)\b`.
The `|` means "OR" and `\b` are word boundaries (to ensure that matches are full words and not part of words).

Comment: Thanks a lot Casimir. Much appreciated. Has anyone tried using PdftoWord to extract to text to word or display in the pages found in Python?